# Automated georeferencing in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I am attempting to fully automate the process of georeferencing a load of .png files - i have xml file containing the co-ordinates - but how can i use them?

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: use a .bat [dos batch] to rename the .xml to a .pgw - if you give an example of the structure of the .xml file it would be easy to see what other factors you require or need. Scale factor/pixel size & rotation.

Comment: Did you see: Work flow for georeferencing imagery using open source tools? <http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/644/work-flow-for-georeferencing-imagery-using-open-source-tools>.

Comment: Well, scripting (python, model builder) requires the georeference toolbar's functions available as tool(s) in the toolbar. However, the tool we were looking for is named **"Warp" (Data Managment, Raster)** and can be easily automated. To make it not too easy, it's not able to accept a same-styled txt file as the georeferencing toolbar will export, but a list of source points and a list of of target points. Regards, Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you will have to create a script in ModelBuilder.

The georeference tool has a way to load the match pairs from txt file.

The format is simple...

1359096.642582  353463.253614   1343639.244522  360489.343642

1513436.420187  348310.787594   1531938.457260  360957.749644

source xy, and map xy.

You should also specify the transformation type. That will depend on how many points you have for each image. 1st, 2nd, or 3rd order polynomial or adjust.

Comment: @Alice Did you find a way to use your xml? I'm sure my answer didn't get you all the way there. Successful implementation would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to convert those PNG images to TIFF, using QUAD-G would be an option. Our recent project was able to georeference tens of thousands of map sheets in a supervised-automated workflow in a short period of time.

The link to the program files and documentation can be found here: https://geography.wisc.edu/quad-g-automated-georeferencing-project/

The program is free and open-sourced, and the files read quickly into ArcGIS Desktop.