# GeoReference tiff image into the Google map?

Tags: c#, geotiff-tiff, .net, georeferencing, google-maps-api

I want to Geo-reference a tiff image contain a Map for a specific region, I need to add this region(image) and Geo-reference it on the Google map, SO I can see on the map for the region I select the image which I have inserted.

the image also need information such as the Latitude and Longitude of corners and size, and the pixel per meter measurement.

How to do the correct Geo-reference for that ?

Comment: You might want to look at: [raster - Work flow for georeferencing imagery using open source tools? - Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/644/work-flow-for-georeferencing-imagery-using-open-source-tools "raster - Work flow for georeferencing imagery using open source tools? - Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange")

Comment: actually I have the tiff image also the world file info to do Georeferencing, but I am not able to do Geo in C# using the GMAP API there ??
yes, by the way, I have the position for each pixel in the tiff image from this link http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files_for_raster_datasets

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGIS Georeferencer plugin: 
http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html

What you will do is open a map in QGIS and and identify control points to define where your tiff file fit inside this map. Then QGIS will export a geo referenced tiff file.

Alternatively, you could do it manually by writing a .wld file. You have to know your image resolution and the latitude and longitude of the tiff corners. Documentation is here:
http://mapserver.org/input/raster.html#georeference-with-world-files

Once your tiff will be georeferenced, either with via QGIS or with a wld file, you will need a map server service to serve it to GoogleMaps. Look for the tutorial for MapServer or GeoServer on Google. If your tiff is not to big, you can also use GDAL2Tile:
http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/

Comment: actually I have the tiff image also the world file info to do Georeferencing, but I am not able to do Geo in C# using the GMAP API there ??
yes, by the way, I have the position for each pixel in the tiff image from this link http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files_for_raster_datasets

Comment: although I have these info but can't do Geo :/

Comment: You can't do C# in the GAMP API. GoogleMaps runs in a browser and only support JavaScript. What you have to do is to configure yourself a WMS server. You can do that with ArcGIS Server or look for OpenSource alternative (MapServer, GeoServer, Mapnik). Once you will have that working, you will be able to display your tiff over GMAP with JavaScript.

Comment: -i need server just to display map over their map?
-also i have install many servers but these need web app to use them ? 
-I have to use javascript ??? can't do it just with c# ?

Comment: The Google Maps API is only available through a browser. It's against the licence to use something else than the JavaScript API to access Google Maps. In short, you do have to use JavaScript and have a web map server to display your raster on top of Google Maps. Please accept an answer or close this question and open a new question if you want details on how to setup a MapServer as it is not related to your original question. I suggest you start here: http://openlayers.org/

Comment: always mark my new questions as duplicated, So if I have the information for Geo and the image just need how to add this image as Geo map on mapServer ?